# GCP Debian Compute Instance Cannot take HTTP or HTTPS traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, virtual-machine, firewall

I have a GCP compute instance that has a docker container set up to listen on ports: 80,443,8080,8443 as follows:

`docker run -it -p 80:5000 -p 8080:5000 -p 443:5001 -p 8443:5001 -v "$(pwd):/src" --name test-container alpine`

Inside the docker container is a basic node.js app:

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 5000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I can see that it is listening by running `sudo ss -ltn -p`:

[image: ss -ltn output]

And I can see that an nmap scan results in only port 22 being open.

I have read many other answers pointing towards the firewall blocking this but I set up this instance with allow http and allow https and it has the same firewall rules as another instance that successfully takes both http and https traffic.

When I curl the IP I get connection refused.

Is there anything that I am doing obviously wrong? I am happy to provide additional information as needed.

I have tried adding a new firewall rule that accepts traffic to these ports from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) to no avail.

Comment: What is running inside the container? Mapping a port does not create something that listens on a port.

Comment: @JohnHanley It is a simple node.js application

Comment: We cannot see what it does or which ports it listens on. Edit your post and add the details required to provide an answer.

Comment: Updated with the node.js app hello world that is running.

Comment: 1) Your post has two images of text. Replace the images with text. Read this [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) and this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 2) Your app only listens on port 5000. Why are you mapping the other ports? 3) Why is your app listening on network `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Thank you, solved by switching hostname from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a hostname, it is a special address that means `all network interfaces` when used with a TCP `bind()` network call.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching `hostname` from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

0.0.0.0 allows the app to listen for incoming connections on all available network interfaces rather than just a single interface.